# Convert empty array string to array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an empty array string

```
String stringArray = "[]";
```

And I want to convert it to an Array type.

I need this because I want to compare in an if statement if the array is empty. Like

```
if(stringArray.isEmpty()){
   // doSomething 
}
```

Any suggestion how I can do this?

Comment: How about simply `stringArray.equals("[]")`? How did you get such a thing in the first place? This sounds very much like an XY problem...

Comment: You *could* (not meaning you should) use a JSON parser to parse this array

Comment: @Sweeper I get it from another system. I extracted it then to a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringArray = "[]";
        Object[] array = JSON.parseArray(stringArray).toArray();
        if (array.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("array is empty");
        }
    }
```

output is:

```
array is empty
```

Comment: you can use more other tools  parse it as a json string to array

Comment: I wanted to try this one, which package or dependency is JSON (JSON.parseArray)?

Answer (score 0):

```java
String stringArray = "[]";
```

In this line, you didn't define an empty array. You have definee new string where the value is **[]**

Use the code below if you would like to define an empty array

```java
String[] stringArray ; //Define string array without initialization
String[] stringArray2 = new String[5];//Define string array with 5 element
```

Comment: Yes I know I defined a string with this "[]" value. This is what I get from another system, that's why I asked how to parse it to an array